# ¿Cómo obtener el primer y último valor de un rango/grupo en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Buen día, estoy atorado en una consulta que no logro resolver, les explico.

Tengo una base de datos con los siguientes datos:

[image]

Y necesito realizar una consulta donde los resultados tengan las siguientes columnas (datos ya agrupados):

[image]

ESTE RESULTADO ESTÁ ERRÓNEO. A esto quiero llegar:

Mi problema es la columna que dice 'INICIO' y 'FINAL' que hace referencia a una agrupación por CENTRO y UR que hice, ¿Cuál es el problema en sí? Obtengo el primer y último valor de esa agrupación con las funciones MIN y MAX, el problema de estas funciones es que busca respecto al número y me interesa que no se cambie ese orden en el que vienen los comprobantes, (Independientemente de que sean unos mayores que otros)

Por ejemplo, en la UR FOR me gustaría saber cómo podría obtener el primer valor que es: 110089668
y el último que es 100788846.

Ordenando por rfc o agrupando no llego a este resultado, ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Mi tabla se compone de los siguiente:

```
   CREATE TABLE `for1421` (
  `RFC` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOMB` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EDDO` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MUNI` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TAB` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AA` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PP` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UR` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PTDA` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COD` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PGAI` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUM` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INMDO` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TITRA` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HORASI` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NIVPTO` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RGO` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PORCPTO` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERPAGI` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERPAGF` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIPAG` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMCHE` text,
  `DIGV` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CTA` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIBA` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INSTRU` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `I1` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `I2` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `I3` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `TTR` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMREG` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRDNAME` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CURP` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EDO` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIPO` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QNA` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ANIO` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QNAC` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ANIOC` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comisionado` varchar(15) DEFAULT 'NO',
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5107 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT emp.CR,cr.DESCRIPCION,cr.JURISDICCION,MIN(numche),MAX(numche),MIN(id),MAX(id)
FROM FOR1421 emp 
INNER JOIN centros AS cr ON emp.CR = cr.CR  
WHERE EMP.INSTRU != '00' AND emp.PRDNAME = 'PRDO140' AND emp.comisionado = 'NO' AND cr.JURISDICCION = 'J-2'
GROUP BY emp.cr,cr.JURISDICCION,emp.UR
ORDER BY cr.JURISDICCION,CR.CR,emp.ur,emp.RFC,emp.INSTRU,emp.id;
```

Mi tabla centros con la que hago el inner join

```
CREATE TABLE `centros` (
  `CR` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `DESCRIPCION` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `JURISDICCION` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PAGADOR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

En sí el problema radica en la obtención del comprobante (NUMCHE).

Adjunto algunos datos:

| rfc | cr | ur | numche | instru |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CUMA860108 | 0030 | FO2 | 100788834 | 10 |
| GAOM830516 | 0030 | FO2 | 100788835 | 10 |
| NUPP720529 | 0030 | FO2 | 100788836 | 10 |
| PEPN741214 | 0030 | FO2 | 100788837 | 10 |
| AARV890203 | 0030 | FO3 | 100788838 | 10 |
| COSA851223 | 0030 | FO3 | 110089667 | 11 |
| FOIV761231 | 0030 | FOR | 110089668 | 11 |
| GAMM740928 | 0030 | FOR | 100788839 | 10 |
| HEOF890511 | 0030 | FOR | 100788840 | 10 |
| LOJI840229 | 0030 | FOR | 100788841 | 10 |
| MACG750830 | 0030 | FOR | 100788842 | 10 |
| MIUI871007 | 0030 | FOR | 110089669 | 11 |
| PAEL830703 | 0030 | FOR | 100788843 | 10 |
| RAMR880809 | 0030 | FOR | 100788844 | 10 |
| SACA600801 | 0030 | FOR | 100788845 | 10 |
| SAMR770216 | 0030 | FOR | 100788846 | 10 |

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Para el MVCE nos vendría bien que compartieras la definición de la tabla (`SHOW CREATE TABLE <tabla>`, a ser posible con algunos datos para probar) además de la consulta SQL que has intentado y te falla.

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿sabías que el orden de los datos almacenados en una tabla podría no coincidir con el orden en el que se introdujeron en ella? Con pocos datos es posible que aún no hayas sufrido fragmentación, pero conforme pase el tiempo se quedarán "huecos" en el espacio de tablas que podría ser ocupados por nuevos registros, alterando el orden de éstos. Deberías almacenar algún dato que te permita restablecer el orden en el que los introdujiste, como una fecha y hora con precisión decimal.

Comment: Hola, claro que sí, adjunto la información que me pides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de algunos intentos, logré resolver mi problema.

Un poco arcaico tal vez, pero funcional, si alguien tiene alguna otra sugerencia, bienvenido.

Lo que hice fue la siguiente consulta:

```
SUBSTRING((MIN(CONCAT(rfc,"-",numche))),15,10) AS 'INICIO',SUBSTRING((MAX(CONCAT(rfc,"-",numche))),15,10) AS 'FINAL'
```

"Anidarlo" de alguna forma con el rfc ya que todos seguían este orden y así no se ordenaran los datos respecto a min y max.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la consulta completa? No tiene mucho sentido que justo este trozo de SQL solucione tu problema. Además, podrías haber indicado que el orden está dado por el valor de `rfc` y no respecto a `numche`. Sabiendo estos datos que no estaban en la pregunta original se podría resolver fácilmente el problema.

Answer (score 1):

A partir de MySql 8.0 puedes utilizar `Window functions` para obtener el primer y último `numche` de cada `ur` ordenando por la columna `rfc`. No se que versión de MySql estás utilizando.

La query la cree a partir de la estructura de los datos de prueba que compartiste (no te las tablas originales, ya que no contaba con datos de prueba para las tablas originales):

```
SELECT DISTINCT cr, 
                FIRST_VALUE(numche) OVER (PARTITION BY ur ORDER BY rfc ASC) AS inicio,
                FIRST_VALUE(numche) OVER (PARTITION BY ur ORDER BY rfc DESC) AS final,
                COUNT(numche) OVER (PARTITION BY ur) AS registros,
                ur
FROM tabla;
```

Salida (con los datos de ejemplo de la pregunta):

| cr | inicio | final | registros | ur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0030 | 100788834 | 100788837 | 4 | FO2 |
| 0030 | 100788838 | 110089667 | 2 | FO3 |
| 0030 | 110089668 | 100788846 | 10 | FOR |

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Estoy algo atrasado, estoy en la versión 5.7, voy a ponerme a investigar sobre las funciones de ventana y desde luego actualizarme! Qué amable amigo, un saludo.

Comment: De nada @RodrigoCortés! Hay muchas mejoras a partir de la versión 8.0.